# Rails Ajax: referencing a div that was named as an iteration in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial-views

I have a view in which I loop through a series of models. In each iteration, I render a bootstrap nav of tabs, followed by a div that I name uniquely in that iteration. That div is filled with various partials specified through rails ajax, depending on which tab is currently clicked. Thus, overall, you can image the view being a series of tabbed-navs, with a table of data underneath each. The code for that looks as follows:

```
<h3>Season Stats</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <% @player.season_stats_season_numbers.each do |season_number_object| %>
                <% season_number = season_number_object.season_number %>
                <%= render partial: "show_season_stats", locals: {season_number_object: season_number_object, season_number: season_number} %>
                <div id=<%="season_stats_div#{season_number}"%>><br></div>
            <% end %>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

The "_show_season_stats" partial renders the bootstrap tabbed-nav, and the line beneath it creates a div that is ID'd by the season number.

I am unable to reference the correct div in my ajax code. For examples, if I wanted to show defensive stats, I have a file show_defensive_stats.js.erb which has the line:

```
$("#season_stats_div#{@season_number}").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'defensive_stats_layout', locals: { defensive_season_stats: @defensive_season_stats } ) %>");
```

When I click the corresponding tab in the nav, nothing happens. I know the rest of the code is working fine, because if I rename the div in the loop to just "season_stats_div," then reference that in my ajax code, ie; $("#season_stats_div".... I get the exact behavior I desire.

How do I properly reference the named divs in the js.erb file?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the raw html that is produced for one of your seasons? and also what is then referenced in `show_defensive_stats.js.erb` ? could just be that: a) one has spaces in it where it shouldn't (or a similar tiny misalignment in naming) or b) `@season_number` isn't being properly set and passed to your js.erb - and so it can't find the right div.

Comment: I don't think it's a simple misalignment in naming, I've checked that carefully, and I don't think it that @season_number isn't being set properly - I added a print statement to the screen using ruby in the show_defensive_stats.js.erb file, and it printed the correct number

Comment: I think maybe it has something to do with the second # symbol? I'm trying to use it to dereference the variable, but I have a feeling I'm not escaping it correctly or something like that

Comment: Part of the problem is I don't know how to debug the js.erb file, I think if I could print out what $("#season_stats_div#{@season_number}").. actually searches for I could figure it out. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: it's an erb file, which means you can enter ruby statements... eg `<% puts "#season_stats_div#{@season_number}".inspect %>` and that should show up in your terminal output (or anything else, like `puts "I got to point 1"` etc :)

Comment: Incidentally: this: `<div id=<%="season_stats_div#{season_number}"%>><br></div>` should be: `<div id="season_stats_div<%= season_number %>"><br></div>`

Comment: Thanks! I printed in the erb file using standard ruby, as you pointed out, and it generates the correct result. However, nothing happens when I click the link, since I think the javascript looks for a div with id season_stats_div#{@season_number}, as opposed to season_stats_div2016, as it should be

Comment: So you're saying you think the js.erb might be looking for `"#season_stats_div#{@season_number}"` ? I agree - that seems likely. well, try using `#season_stats_div<%= season_number %>` in the js.erb as well? :)

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: "it didn't work" doesn't help us figure out what went wrong or what we can do to fix it... Can you please explain what you observed actually happening, and what you tried to find out what was going on?

Comment: Here's what I mean: if I simply name the relevant div as <div class="season_stats_div"... with the same in the show_defensive_stats.js.erb file, then clicking on the nav tab "defensive stats" for year 2016 will render defensive stats in that div. However, since that div is singularly named, and not uniquely named, clicking on defensive stats for year 2015 renders those stats in the same div, instead of the div beneath the nav tabs for year 2015. When I try to uniquely name the divs by year, and use your suggestion in the .js.erb file, then clicking defensive stats does not render any stats

Comment: The original example you used when talking about uniquely naming the div used ruby string-interpolation (ie with `#{}`) whereas I've suggested changing that to erb-interpolation (ie `<%= %>`). You will definitely need to do this, even if it doesn't "work" yet... because your js-file is in erb, not ruby. However... once you have done it - there may still be another bug... but you can hopefully at least attempt to look in the console for js bugs now.